# How to get column name in tab separated dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a tab separated file which I extracted in pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(r"C:\Users\Ashish\Documents\indeed_ml_dataset\train.tsv", sep="\t")
```

data1

Here is how the data1 looks like:

[image: data1 dataframe pandas]

Now, I want to view the column name tags. I don't know whether I should call it a column or not, but I have tried accessing it using the norm:

```
data2=data1[['tags']]
```

but it errors out. I have tried several other things as well using `index` and `loc`, but all of them fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AndrewL: In a way. I actually want the tags column values.

Comment: @AndrewL: Exactly. Even I don't get it. But this is the way this data file has been provided actually and pandas converted it in this way. So, not sure how can I read specific column in this.

Comment: `Index(['description'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Shows only one column. on trying `data1.columns`

Comment: it errors out with below error:

`KeyError: 'the label [tags] is not in the [index]'`

Comment: @AndrewL: If I execute: `data1.index[0]`, it returns me the first row under tags column.

`licence-needed supervising-job 5-plus-years-experience-needed`

Comment: Hmm ok it looks like for some reason it's reading in the description as the Index. Try data1.reset_index() and see if you get a new column name "0". This will allow you to set index as the 0 column.

Comment: @AndrewL: It worked. I created a new dataframe using 
`data2=data1.reset_index()`
After that, I am able to access `data2['tags']` as expected. Thanks @AndrewL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you'll need to remove description from the index by resetting. Try the below:

```
data2 = data1.reset_index()
data2['tags']
```

You'll then be able to select by "tags".

Answer (score 1):

Try reading your data using **pd.read_csv** instead of **pd.DataFrame.from_csv** as  it takes first column as index by default.
For more info refer to this documentation on pandas website: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html